# jQuery / JavaScriptが無効の環境でも表示を保証するには

Tags: javascript, jquery

実際に動かしたい内容としては[jQuery / JavaScriptで、ロード画面を表示させたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/510/jquery-javascript%E3%81%A7-%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E7%94%BB%E9%9D%A2%E3%82%92%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)とほぼ同じで、以下のことを行いたいのですが、

1. HTML読み込み完了後まで要素を非表示
2. 完了後にアニメーションとともに要素を表示する

要素にclassで`display: none;`を付けた状態にしておき、読み込み完了後にjQueryの`toggleClass`で外して表示するという方法で目的を達成することができます。  
ですが、この場合の問題点としてJavaScriptが無効の時に読み込みが完了しても要素が表示されないという点が上げられます。

なるべくCSSでのアニメーションに依存（しなくてもOK）しながらJavaScriptが使用できない環境でも表示を保証するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか。

---

**追記:**

`<noscript>`を使って以下の様なコードで表示は保証されますが、この場合記述量が2倍近くに膨れ上がり、またSEO的にも悪いのでこのような方法を避けたいです。

```
<div id="wrapper" class="is-hidden">
  <h1>TEST</h1>
  <p>messege</p>
</div>
<noscript>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <p>messege</p>
  </div>
</noscript>
```

---

**実際に動かしたいアニメーションの例：**

[image: 実際に動かしたいアニメーションの例]

```js
$(window).load(function() {
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("is-hidden animated fadeInDown");
      });
```

```css
.is-hidden {
      display: none;
    }

/* Animate.css */
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
          animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="is-hidden">
  <h1>TEST</h1>
  <p>messege</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
シンプルにこれだけで良くない？

 <style> /* デフォルトは非表示 */
  .test { display: none;}
 </style>

 <noscript>
  <style> /* cssでは呼び出し方法とセレクターが同じであれば後から読み込まれた方が有効になる */
   .test { display: block;}
  </style>
 </noscript>

 <div class="test" >
  TEST
 </div>
```

Comment: その方法には気が付かなかったです…！実際に動くのでシンプルに解決されますね。`head`内に記述して`link`要素で別のCSSを読み込むという方法もできるのでいいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

JSが有効の時にだけ有効になるCSSを使えばいいと思います。

まず、`<html>`たぐに`no-js`のクラスを加えます。

```
<html class="no-js">
```

そして、`head`の中にそのクラスを外すJSを入れます（外部.jsファイルに入れても可）。

```
<script>
    var htmlEl = document.documentElement;
    htmlEl.className = htmlEl.className.replace("no-js", "js");
</script>
```

そうすれば、JS無効/有効別のCSSが使えます。

```
<style>
    .js is-hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: JavaScriptが実行可能か判別してclassを変更して行う方法はスマートだと(個人的には)思います。ただ、スマートフォン等のscript実行が遅い環境だと一瞬表示されてしまうのが悩みになります。それを含めて解決できればと思います。

Comment: @koluku 通常の場合は`script`の実行が終わるまでその後のDOMの構成が進まないものです。だから以上のスクリプトを`head`の中に入れれば（ファイルで参照した場合でも）、スクリプトの実行が終わる前にページが表示される心配はないと思います。

Comment: `head`内で`link`もしくは`style`よりも前に`script`を配置することで表示の問題は解決されるわけですね。レンダリングが若干遅くなりますが確かにこの問題は解決されますね。

Comment: @koluku ページのコンテンツが入っている`body`より前にさえ配置していれば、`head`の中でどこに入れてもいいです。

Answer (score 1):

いろいろやり方はあると思いますけど、その方向性だと、まず `<noscript>` を普通に記述して、その後 JS を使って、 `<noscript>` を剥ぎ取ってやればよいです。

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<noscript>
  <h1>TEST</h1>
  <p>messege</p>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('noscript').replaceWith(function() {return this.textContent || this.innerText;});
</script>
```

追記: Googleクローラ から見ると、上記のページは以下のように見えます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: その場合、読み込み完了時点で「JavaScript実行可能時は何も表示されない」と解釈された後で表示されるようになるのでは無いでしょうか？それは文書として問題があるように僕は思いますが、どうでしょうか。

Comment: 文章として、というのは目的によりますが、「Javascript でしかうまく表示されないページのために代替コンテンツを含む」とは、`<noscript>`の存在意義そのものですので、HTMLコンテンツとしては問題ないでしょう。今回の場合、スパム判定に重要だろう「Javascript で生成されるコンテンツが、<noscript> の中身と同じになるようにする」という要素もクリアしています。まあ、強引な手法なのは間違いないですけどね。。。

Searchbility を気にしてらっしゃるのでしたら最終的には bot が解釈するかが判断材料になるのかと思います。そうであれば、大手の検索エンジンの bot は `<noscript>` を解釈します。( 例: http://www.nickpower.com/google-index-links-noscript-tag/ ) 

せっかくだから、 Bot から見たページも張っておきますね。